# Configure istio to not intercept traffic to serviceB:port

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am new to istio. Istio intercepts all traffic between two services through istio-proxy/envoy. Is it possible to configure istio so that it ignores certain type of traffic

- when serviceA makes an https call directly to serviceB on a certain port
- UDP traffic

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per Istio [sidecar injection configuration](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml) you can exclude ports from Envoy & iptables rules using the `includeInboundPorts` and `excludeInboundPorts` annotations.

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: podinfo
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: podinfo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: podinfo
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: "*"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "9999,9229"
      labels:
        app: podinfo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: podinfod
        image: quay.io/stefanprodan/podinfo:1.4.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9898
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9999 # <- excluded port
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 9229 # <- excluded port
          protocol: TCP
        command:
        - ./podinfo
        - --port=9898
        - --level=info
```

Comment: this doesnt work (At least not by default in istio 1.2.0) https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/files/injection-template.yaml#L194 has a value and seems to ignore annotation

Comment: Not working for me, it seems like ignored